# When the completed filtration of a process increases slowly

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, filtrations, stochastic-differential-equations

If $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the filtration of the evaluation process on $C_T$ (continuous function on $[0,T]$). Can we find some law of continuous process $\mathbb{P}$ so that for $t\leq T$
$$\mathcal{F}^{\mathbb{P}}_{t} \cap \mathcal{F}_T \subset \mathcal{F}_t$$ - $(\mathcal{F}^{\mathbb{P}}_t)$ is the completion of $\mathcal{F}_t$ (by null sets of $\mathcal{F}_T$). Obviously it doesn't hold for a Dirac. Does it work for the Brownian motion or other processes ?

Comment: @ Filtrask : For the natural filtration of a Brownian motion $\mathcal{F}_0$ includes negligible sets (true for Lévy processes also), so your property is fulfilled. Otherwise I don't get your point on Dirac. Best regards.

Comment: Is is a convention that all the negligible sets for the law of the Brownian motion are in $\sigma(X_0)$ or is this a result ? I remember that $\mathcal{F}_0^+$ is trivial (Blumenthal 0-1), is this related to your result ? Can i have a reference because i'm ashamed to recognize i didn't remember this result. (For the Dirac we have $\mathcal{F}_t^P\cap \mathcal{F}_T = \mathcal{F}_T$ which is not a subset of $\mathcal{F}_t$)

Comment: @ Filtrask : This is called the usual aumgentation and together with right continuity of the filtration, it ensures existence of "good" modification of processes (usually existence of càdlàg version of martingales). For Feller processes the augmentation with negligible sets of the filtration is enough to ensure right conitnuity of the filtration. You can check Katratzas and Shreve's book (and P. Protter's book for the last point on Feller processes). Best regards